# How to centre a div inside a div?

Tags: html, css

How can a centre a div inside another div (both vertically and horizontaly) using CSS?
My html is

`<div class='outer'><div class='inner'></div></div>`

And CSS -

```
.outer{
position: realative;
top:20%;
left20%;
width:500px;
height:500px;
background:red;
}
.inner{
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#ff2;
/*code to align in centre*/
}
```

Comment: here is the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/6kdpec0s/37/

Answer (score 0):

```
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties to the outer div:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

It will center the content.
Alternatively you could add this to the inner:

```
position: relative;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Above it will push itself from all sides.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches since it's a common issue:

**Transform**

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

`left` and `top` will translate the item within the parent, and `transform` will translate it relative to its top left corner.

`position: fixed;` also work as long as you know the differences between `absolute` and `fixed`.

**Flexbox**

You need to work with the parent. You must set the following properties to the parent:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

The child should also have `display: flex;` for easy handling, but it's not mandatory. `position: absolute;` is not necessary with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
.inner{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 5.5em;
    background-color: #8880;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Mainly doing the help for the answer and that would be like that way! The way wanted to actually do with.

Answer (score -1):

Use `display:flex;`

```
.outer{
position: realative;
top:20%;
left:20%;
width:500px;
height:500px;
background:red;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
.inner{
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#ff2;
/*code to align in centre*/
}
```

```css
.outer{
position: realative;
top:20%;
left:20%;
width:500px;
height:500px;
background:red;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
.inner{
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#ff2;
/*code to align in centre*/
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'><div class='inner'></div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/jqxtuvLz/1/

Comment: @Manjuboyz check question